How can my custom error handler detect if the same error will also be thrown by PHP as an ErrorException?
I'm trying to update an older application to make use of newer PHP 8.2+ features. Many internal PHP errors are now automatically thrown as ErrorException objects.
You can set up a custom function to handle any ErrorException objects that are thrown but not caught.
The issue is that sometimes, however, PHP seems to be throwing both an ErrorException object and also using the old error handler at the same time. This results in the same error being processed twice.
Please consider the following simplified code:
// Setup Error Handling
ErrorHandler::Init();

// Try to include a file that doesn't exist:
require '/path/to/nothing.php';

// The simple error class:
abstract class ErrorHandler {
   
   static public function Init(){
      set_exception_handler('ErrorHandler::FinalException');
      set_error_handler('ErrorHandler::BasicErrorHandler');
   }
   
   static public function FinalException($e){
      echo '<br>FinalException() TRIGGERED!<br>';      
   }
   
   static public function BasicErrorHandler($errorNo){
      echo '<br>ErrorHandler() TRIGGERED!<br>';
   }
}

When the missing file error occurs, the output is:
ErrorHandler() TRIGGERED!
FinalException() TRIGGERED!

That is, both the exception handler and the error handler are running for the same error.
If possible, I'd rather just use exceptions. But if I don't use set_error_handler(), I still get a standard error message in addition to the exception. It just doesn't get passed to a handler.

Is it possible to set a flag that turns off all of the old style error handling and uses only exceptions, so that I don't need to set set_error_handler() in addition to set_exception_handler()?

If not, how can I detect inside my custom error handler (which always runs first) if the same error will also be thrown by PHP as an ErrorException so it doesn't get handled twice?



Maybe throw an exception inside your error handler?

It's generally bad practice to mess with the runtime side of things. A be good to your neighbor deal (don't try to force Exceptions into Errors or vice versa). So, to have better habits, we take advantage of the Throwable class, which all things Thrown in PHP must extend. Thus, the example below will catch any Error or Exception. Disclaimer some ERRORS like E_DEPRECATED CANNOT BE CAUGHT in a try-catch block, and some RECOVERABLE_WARNINGS are actually fatal like max file descriptors reached. So the set_exception_handler and set_error_handler may be fired in extremely poor circumstances and when you'd never expect them. Once called, Errors can compound easily. Having your error catcher get called on its-self will happen, and you need to be super fault tolerant not to have it recurse into oblivion. If your fans start to spin and the request hasn't come back, you've probably reached this situation.
I have written an error handling library ThrowableHandler.php.
try {

            
} catch (Throwable $e) {

    ThrowableHandler::generateLog($e);

}

If you reference my repo, you'll see the set_exception_handler and set_error_handler, which basically just call generateLog.
Edit:
Look at this example

<?php
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");

This will fall back into the try-catch. Using the global error handler, it is possible to return to the current step of the script execution and continue. However, this is also extremely hard to manage and wouldn't be recommended for actual Errors. The code above will "fall" back into the try-catch. Using this code however is a bad practice, and if I saw someone do this in library code (open source) without at the very least changing the global error handler back to the default or better what it was previously set to... I'd remove that code immediately.
You are essentially going to take E_WARNING, E_NOTICE, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_WARNING, E_USER_WARNING, E_USER_NOTICE, and E_USER_DEPRECATED, which can all be recovered from and not fail, to fail on these. Ew. But it's your code, not mine, so have fun.

Do we know if there are still any cases (PHP 8.2+) where an error would be the old type that needs a set_error_handler() method, but is not also a throwable? Or in other words, if we only catch throwable and don't set an old style error handler, will anything be missed?

I'm not sure I understand. You need to catch both globally definingset_exception_handler and  set_error_handler  but you only ever need to end a try catch with } catch (Throwable $e) { as it will capture the 'new and old style'. I'm on the PHP internals mailing list and can say everyone is pretty against backward incompatibilities, like changing all the error types. Uniformity is not the priority, consistency is.

After playing with this for a bit, it looks like warnings and notices will never get caught by a catch (Throwable $e) block, and the only way to process warnings and notices is to also have a function set with set_error_handler(). What I was getting at with my question was, can we do all error processing in PHP 8.2+ with only exceptions? But from experimenting, it seems that we must still use set_error_handler() if we want to process warnings and notices in the code.

@Nick threw an edit in the post to talk about that ^
